# javascript and mustache - passing an array to template

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I am trying to learn mustache / icanhaz in conjunction with jquery and javascript, and I've got a mustache template to which I'm passing various data. One of the pieces of data is a list of choices, but that list can vary in length (say, one to three choices). How do I pass that varying data to mustache?

This is my code:

Javascript:

```
for (childIndex in scenes[sceneID].children) {
    childSceneID = scenes[sceneID].children[childIndex];
    childScene = scenes[childSceneID];
    childLink = childScene.name;
}

decision = ich.decision(decisionData);
$('#page_container').append(decision);
```

Template:

```
<script id="decision" type="text/html">
        <div id="page">
            <h1>{{ tTitle }}</h1>
            <ul id="options">
                <li>{{tDecision}}</li>
            </ul>
            {{#tBacklink}}<a id="back" data-sceneid="{{tBacklink}}">Back</a>{{/tBacklink}}
        </div>
    </script>
```

So somehow I have to pass all the childLinks in the decision object to mustache to be parsed in a loop to output the list of `<li>` elements.

Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Model your data in an object first of all,

```
var scene = {
  tTitle: '',
  tDecision: '',
  tBacklink: ''
};
```

Then place each of these objects in an array on each iteration of your loop

```
var scenes = [];

for () {
  scenes.push(scene);
}
```

Then call Mustache to render the template with the scenes array, the template has been modified like this

```
<script id="decision" type="text/html">
  <div id="page">
    {{#scenes}}
      <h1>{{ tTitle }}</h1>
      <ul id="options">
        <li>{{tDecision}}</li>
      </ul>
      {{#tBacklink}}<a id="back" data-sceneid="{{tBacklink}}">Back</a>{{/tBacklink}}
    {{/scenes}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Well, the only thing is - it's not all of the data that needs to be looped through, it's only tDecision that would have multiple values. I think I am going to delete this question - I started a new one here that might be clearer and more to the point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071193/javascript-jquery-creating-an-object-in-a-particular-format-from-a-loop

Comment: Basically, I have something that is working, only it is not spitting out a separate li for each tDecision, it just generates a comma delimited list

Comment: If you post some code I can take a look. Surely you can figure out where to go from here based on my answer? To debug, log the array before templating and log the html afterwards.

Comment: Yes - I think I can figure it out. Thank you.