# javascript / jquery - creating an object in a particular format from a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I'm trying to get some data into this format, for use with a templating system called mustache:

```
{
  "repo": [
    { "name": "resque" },
    { "name": "hub" },
    { "name": "rip" },
  ]
}
```

and what I currently have is this:

```
for (childIndex in scenes[sceneID].children) {  
    childSceneID = scenes[sceneID].children[childIndex];
    childScene = scenes[childSceneID];
}
```

So I somehow need to make each childScene the "name" in the "repo" object. Does anyone know how to do this? This is the mustache documentation:

http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html

Comment: Which `name` in the `repo` object? There are 3 different ones.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript and mustache - passing an array to template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071081/javascript-and-mustache-passing-an-array-to-template)

Comment: Sorry - I couldn't delete that question, but I think this is more to the point of what I'm trying to solve. Each childscene would be a name, and those names would be pushed as part of the overall template object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you meant?:

```
var repo = [];

for (childIndex in scenes[sceneID].children) {  
    childSceneID = scenes[sceneID].children[childIndex];
    childScene = scenes[childSceneID];
    repo.push({"name": childScene});
}

var theobj = { "repo": repo };
```

Comment: @mheavers I spelt child wrong before, I had `childe`. Was that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just put this here

```
var repo = new Object();
var table = new Object();
repo["repo"] = table;
table["name1"] = "resque";
table["name1"] = "hub";
table["name1"] = "rip";
```